# Using a redirect URL parameter in WebForm_PostBackOptions

Tags: javascript, custom-form, save

I have a custom list form in SharePoint Online 2013 which after validating using the PreSave() function displays a modal dialog giving the user a choice of two outcomes.  This works fine and the user is returned to the lists's AllItems.aspx page.

What I would like to do is return the user to the site's Home Page and have tried to achieve this by using the following code:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(saveButtonName, "", true, "", "https://[mydomain].sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/Home%20Page.aspx", false, true));
```

The url is valid, and redirects correctly, but I am returned with a SharePoint error:

> ### Sorry, something went wrong
>
> This Page has been modified since you opened it. You must open the page again.

Is there a way to overcome this issue or should I be using another way to skin this particular cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about relying on the `Source` querystring instead?

Here is a crude example of what I'm getting at:

```
(function(w) {
  w.PreSaveAction = function() {
    return w.confirm('Have you been working on it?');
  };

  var source = '/sites/dev/SitePages/Home%20Page.aspx';
  var loc = w.location;
  var s = loc.search;
  if (s.indexOf(source) >= 0) return;

  loc.href = loc.href.replace(/\?.*/, '') + '?' + s.replace(/\?/, '').split('&').filter(function(q) { 
    return !q.match(/^source/i); 
  }).join('&') + '&Source=' + source;
})(window);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm currently focussed elsewhere but will give your suggestion a try in a few days